# How to delist of array from np.split() for function argument

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, kruskal-wallis

Suppose I have data as in array

```
X =  [ x1 x2 ... xn ]
```

when I use np.split(X,n) will separate in to this

```
ARR = [ [arr1] ,[arr2] ,.... [arrn] ]
```

Now I would get those group of array list into function as an input

In this case scipy.stats.kruskal

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.kruskalwallis.html

Here are sample

```
random_array = np.arange(1000)
list_array = np.array_split(random_array, 4)
```

as for the example I can use kruskal function to calculate

```
from scipy.stats import kruskal

kruskal(list_array[0],list_array[1],list_array[2],list_array[3])
```

The problem is I don't want write iterate list_array[0] to list_array[3]  but I want to pass variable list_array into argument direct

```
kruskal(list_array)
```

as all data as inside data argument. is there a way to delist array and pass it all array inside as and argument?

Comment: That's what the star operator is for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-and-doublestar-operator-mean-in-a-function-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what the star operator (`*`) does:

Instead of `kruskal(list_array[0], list_array[1], list_array[2], list_array[3])`

you can write: `kruskal(*list_array)` for arbitrary lengths of `list_array`.

For more information: [What does the star and doublestar operator mean in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-and-doublestar-operator-mean-in-a-function-call)